# Class to represent a mathematical vector of doubles

Tags: java, math, vector

I need a class to represent vectors of doubles (in the mathematical sense).

Particular features I need:

- Arbitrary-dimension vectors (I'm typically using 10 - 100,000 dimensions)
- High performance (it's for CPU-bound numerical code)
- Mutable
- Basic vector maths operations supported (addition, scaling etc.)
- Ability to take sub-vectors (e.g. consider the 100th-200th elements as a new vector)
- Serializable

Is there a good standard implementation of such a class in an existing Java library or should I roll my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout  [Efficient Java Matrix Library](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/)

Its design goals are (http://java.dzone.com/announcements/efficient-java-matrix-library)

1. to be as computationally and memory efficient as possible for both small and large matrices, and
2. to be accessible to both novices and experts. These goals are accomplished by dynamically selecting the best algorithms to use at runtime and by designing a clean API.

**Others**

[matrix-toolkits-java](http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/)

[Universal Java Matrix Package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ujmp/)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - the benchmarks for EJML are certainly impressive - http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/wiki/RuntimePerformanceBenchmark